# Wix: Add shortcut not in a subfolder!

Tags: wix, shortcut, subdirectory

I want to add a shortcut in my program menu. i tried:

`<Component Id='myId' Guid='E4DED108-0129-4a5b-83FE-C9D1E3025B00'>
            <File Id='MyFileID' Name='Prog.exe' DiskId='1' Source='.\Prog.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
              <Shortcut Id='myShortcut' Name='Prog' Icon='MyIcon.exe' IconIndex='0' Directory='ProgramMenuDir' Advertise='yes' />
            </File>
          </Component>`
but the installer add the shortcut in a subfolder in the program menu! Why and what can i do to avoid this?

Thanks Micha

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change Directory='ProgramMenuDir' into Directory='ProgramMenuFolder', otherwise make a seperate shortcuts component;

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Component Id="Shortcuts"  Guid="{}">
      <Shortcut Id='myShortcut' Name='Prog' Icon='MyIcon.exe' IconIndex='0' Directory='ProgramMenuFolder' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Target="[INSTALLDIR]Prog.exe" />
      <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='SOFTWARE\prog\prog' Type='string' Value='1' KeyPath='yes' />
    </Component>
  </Directory>

  <!-- other files -->
</Directory>
```